# Determining whether the origin is an attracting fixed point for a scalar system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have been asked to determine and prove the attraction properties of a continuous-time dynamical system, generated by the ODE 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} =-x
\end{equation}
which gives the system 
\begin{equation}
S_tx=x_0e^{-t}. 
\end{equation}
For the compact invariant set $I=\{0\}$ I need to work out whether it attracts points in a neighbourhood of $I$, attracts points in the set of all real numbers, attracts all compact sets in $\Re$, or attracts all sets in $\Re$. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider $\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)$